# Debugging a coredump generated by an ASLR enabled system

Tags: gdb, coredump, aslr, postmortem-debugging

I have a coredump extracted from a remote target in production. I need to debug it on my own computer since the target lacks gdb-server. Locally, I have the corresponding tooling, debug symbols and source code.

The problem is that when I load this core into gdb most, if not all, addresses and symbols are not resolved:

```
#15 0x00007ffc78fd87a0 in ?? ()
#16 0x0000000002147bb0 in ?? ()
#17 0x00007ffc78fd8740 in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000000000006 in ?? ()
#19 0x0000332d70667351 in ?? ()
#20 0x00000000021612a0 in ?? ()
#21 0x00007ffc78fd8760 in ?? ()
#22 0x0000000000000006 in ?? ()
#23 0x0000332d70667351 in ?? ()
#24 0x00000000021612a0 in ?? ()
#25 0x0000000000000012 in ?? ()
#26 0x00000000021468e0 in ?? ()
```

If I recompile some module of the application with `-no-pie -fno-PIE`, the frames for that exact module become available. However, that is not an option. The target is in production and needs this security feature enabled.

My main goal is to *have some way of debugging this system post-mortem* in another computer since the only thing I'll have from a crash is a coredump that I can extract. Is there any way around this? Am I missing something? Perhaps, some way of embedding the exact memory offsets that were used when the application was running to the coredump; in a way that gdb will read.

Comment: ASLR is irrelevant -- the most likely root cause is system library mismatch, If you provide correct system libraries (as the linked answer shows) GDB will recover at-runtime addresses on its own.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I assumed the libraries were OK since the result of ```info sharedlibrary``` showed that all libraries were loaded from the correct path (corresponding sysroot). These are unstripped matching versions of the system libraries running on the target. I assumed that this was ASLR fault when I started experimenting with ```-no-pie -fno-PIE``` and suddenly more frames were becoming available. In this case, I was able to substitute the ones on the target. I'm trying to setup the debug workflow, the target is not really deployed.

Comment: If you are already using `sysroot`, then this is _probably_ not a duplicate, so I reopened this. But you should edit your question to show _exactly_ what you've done and what you see.

Answer (score 1):

After two days and I've just figured it out. A rookie mistake.

I was calling gdb on the .debug version of the app instead of the app itself:

```
$ cd ~/sysroot
$ x86_64-linux-gdb usr/bin/.debug/app -c <path_to_dump>
```

instead of:

```
$ cd ~/sysroot
x86_64-linux-gdb usr/bin/app -c <path_to_dump>
```

I've been reusing that command from bash history for the past 2 days and it was giving me a false positive. I corrected it and all symbols show up.